# Remove gridlines in AngularCharts

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using [AngularCharts](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) which is a AgnularJS wrapper for Chart.js. I want to remove all grid lines from my chart so there is just the actual line chart only. But the grids are not being removed.

Controller

```
 $scope.labelsx2 = [" ", " ", " ", " Time ago ", " ", " ", " "];
 $scope.seriesx2 = [' '];
 $scope.datax2 = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
 ]; 
 $scope.options = {
            scaleShowGridLines : false
          };     


 $scope.labelsx2 = [" ", " ", " ", " Time ago ", " ", " ", " "];
 $scope.seriesx2 = [' '];
 $scope.datax2 = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
 ]; 
 $scope.options = {
            scaleShowGridLines : false
          };
```

Chart.html

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="datax2" labels="labelsx2" legend="true" series="seriesx2" options="{showTooltips: false}"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can apply below option to remove grid lines.This works for me.

```
$scope.options = {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
        }],
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
        }]
            }
        };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the html:

Remove the `options="{showTooltips: false}"` to `chart-options="options"`

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" data="datax2" labels="labelsx2" legend="true" series="seriesx2" chart-options="options"></canvas>
```